# Projection matrices onto a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do you show that if $A$ and $B$ are the projection matrices (orthogonal matrices) onto a subspace $V$, then $A=B$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I presume the projection is onto $V$. The full space may be written $V \oplus V^\perp$. What is the image of a vector in the direct sum? This defines the orthogonal projection matrix uniquely.